# Intercom device, door-opener and door-bell

Tags: communication

I got a Bticino intercom system (non-wireless). I did some restoration in my hallway and disconnected the device. Unfortunately I do not remember how it was wired before I set it up afterwards. Now we got a new common door, so I dunno if it is connected to the intercom system.

I've tried to find a manual of this, but this is an older system and I can't seem to find anything related to it. The wires are differently colored, and ive tried all sorts of connections.

[image]

The thing is, I should be able to open the common door for visitors with this unit. And it is also a door-bell (I dunno where the speaker is however) so visitors can ring from outside.

Im not sure where these wires should go, and I also do not know how to be able to open the outer door from this unit. Also on the bottom right of the picture there is a switch.

Comment: Any chance you can find the model number?

Comment: Questions about the *usage* and/or *repair* of *products* are not on topic here.

Comment: Find your model or similar here and follow the instructions: https://www.download.bticino.it/bticino/action/browseItems?categoryId=3441&categoryTypeId=1

Comment: Problem is, I dunno where to find the model number. @Chris Stratton: since you say so, so where are those topics, because it took me a while to search for a tag for these systems.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ok, I will look for it there. thanks

Comment: @NaturalNumberGuy it's not clear that there is a place for this in the stack exchange system.  The founding philosophy of these sites is only to handle fully documented questions which can be dealt with in a specific way.  They exist in very intentional contrast to traditional internet discussion forums.

Comment: I took up the project again. And using the "brute-force" method i managed to make it work. Since there are 24 permutations, this distinct wires. From left to right: orange, orange/white, blue/white and blue setup worked! I should have been doing this a long time ago, but its better late than never.